# How to pair an iOS device to other device around through bluetooth and setting PIN programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, mfi

I have connected External accessory device certified under MFI license with iOS device manually then I Tried to connect the same accessory device programmatically ..  Is there a way to pair an iOS device to other device by bluetooth and enter the PIN programmatically using swift ?

Comment: Since your question is too broad you will probably be downvoted. You need to add more details showing what you already tried and probably split it over multiple questions.

Comment: Done I have edited the description